# Guice and JSR-330

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, jsr330

JSR-330 specifies certain naming conventions in terms of packages, for example:

```
javax.inject.Inject
javax.inject.Scope
```

Guice is the Reference Implementation of JSR-330. However, when using it, you notice that it doesn't follow the spec. For example:

```
com.google.inject.Inject
com.google.inject.Scope
```

This doesn't happen in any of the reference implementations I have seen so far. What makes Google Guice so special that being the RI they can just ignore the specification they are implementing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Guice 3 supports JSR 330 annotations. It also supports the `com.google` annotations for backwards compatibility with earlier versions of Guice (when JSR 330 didn't exist yet).